# Reading text file that is "next line delimited"

Tags: r, import, read.table

I'm not sure how to phrase this question correctly, so I'll give an example.
Let say I have a `.txt` file where the first row is a DATE and the second is a TEXT. Then the pattern repeats, 3rd rows is DATE, 4th is TEXT. 
How would I read this into `R` and convert it into two column `dataframe`.
Essentially I see it as being "next line delimited", not sure if this is a correct way to describe it.

Here is a sample data that would be saved in a `.txt` file:

```
.LOG
3:42 PM 12/04/2019
Task 1
3:45 PM 12/04/2019
Task 2
3:55 PM 13/04/2019
Task 3
3:47 PM 15/04/2019
```

I want it to look like:

```
DATE                TEXT
3:42 PM 12/04/2019  Task 1
3:45 PM 12/04/2019  Task 2
3:55 PM 13/04/2019  Task 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is much better option with `matrix` method

```
as.data.frame(matrix(trimws(df$V1), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, 
          dimnames = list(NULL, c("DATE", "TEXT"))))
#               DATE   TEXT
#1 3:42 PM 12/04/2019 Task 1
#2 3:45 PM 12/04/2019 Task 2
#3 3:55 PM 13/04/2019 Task 3
```

after reading the dataset

#### data

```
df <- read.table("file.txt", sep = "\n")
```

Comment: Am I correct to say that this will scale to any size df? In other words if there were 3 column that had to be filled in using the first 3 rows I would just replace `ncol = 3`?

Comment: @jmich738 Yes, you are right and assuming that the rows are a multiple of 3

Answer (score 4):

Read the file using `read.table` with `sep = "\n"` so you'll have single column dataframe

```
df <- read.table(text = "3:42 PM 12/04/2019
                 Task 1
                 3:45 PM 12/04/2019
                 Task 2
                 3:55 PM 13/04/2019
                 Task 3", sep = "\n")
```

For reading it from a file do

```
df <- read.table("path_of_the_file.txt", sep = "\n")
```

Now split it into two columns by selecting alternate rows

```
data.frame(Date = df[c(TRUE, FALSE), ], Text = df[c(FALSE, TRUE), ])

#               Date    Text
#1 3:42 PM 12/04/2019 Task 1
#2 3:45 PM 12/04/2019 Task 2
#3 3:55 PM 13/04/2019 Task 3
```

Comment: This seems like a very creative solution.Can you please explain how it works?  
I understand that for a `df[Row, Column]`. So for the Row argument why does `c(T,F)` work? I would have thought that to do it this way you would need to state T/F for each row?
Thanks

Comment: @jmich738 the `TRUE`/`FALSE` value is recycled so it automatically selects alternate row irrespective of number of rows. You can check `c(1:10)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` and `c(1:10)[c(FALSE, TRUE)]` to understand how it works.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
 MessyData <- read.table("Myfile.txt")
 CleanData <- data.frame(DATE = MessyData[seq(1, length(MessyData), by = 2)],
                         TEXT = MessyData[seq(2, length(MessyData), by = 2)])
```

Comment: I can't get this one to work.
the first line, without having `sep="\n"` it gives me an error `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, : line 6 did not have 3 elements`.  
But once I add  `sep="\n"` and run line 2 it give me error `Error in seq.default(2, length(MessyData), by = 2) : wrong sign in 'by' argument`

Comment: Yes, that was just where I'd start to try to read in the file, but it's hard to troubleshoot any problems you have with reading the file without me actually having the file. :-) As for the error you still get when you add sep = "\n", it's probably b/c you now have a data.frame. You'd want to change "length" in my answer to "nrow".